# make a condition that can index the datasets together in a correct way in flutter

Tags: flutter, dataset

I have a question about when I use two different datasets (Images & users). The image dataset includes images of a product and the users dataset includes the products information. Both datasets include IDs which is good because that is how I can identify what picture is connected to the correct product information.

So the problem I have now is to somehow make a condition that can index the datasets together in a correct way.

`

```
return Column(
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
  Categories(),

  Expanded(
      child:ListView.builder(
  itemCount: users.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
   return Container(
     padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
     height: 220,
     width: double.maxFinite,
     child: Card(
     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
       elevation: 3,

     child: InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(
           links: images[index],
            products: users[index],
          ),
        ),
      );
    // Function is executed on tap.
          },

              child: new Stack(
           children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                 vertical: 16.0
               ),

             alignment: FractionalOffset.centerLeft,
         child: new Image.network(images[index].plink.toString() ?? ''
         ),
      ),
       Container(
         margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(96.0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0),
         constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(),
         child: new Column(
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
           children: <Widget>[
             new Container(height: 2.0),
             new Text("${users[index].productNameBold??'NoInformation'}",
               style: Style.headerTextStyle,
             ),
             new Container(height: 5.0),
             new Text("${users[index].category??'NoInformation'}",
                 style: Style.baseTextStyle
             ),

             new Container(
                 margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                 height: 2.0,
                 width: 24.0,
                 color: Colors.black
             ),

             new Container(height: 5.0),
             new Text("${users[index].country??'NoInformation'}",
                 style: Style.baseTextStyle
             ),
             new Container(height: 25.0),
             new Row(
               children: <Widget>[
                 new Text("${users[index].price??'NoInformation'} SEK",
                   style: Style.pricetextdiscount,
                 ),
                 new Container(width: 8.0),
                 new Text("129",
                   style: Style.pricetextprevious,
                 ),
               ],
             ),
           ],
         ),
       ),
        ]),
         ),
      ),
        );
     },
      ),
    ),
     ],
      );`
```

EDIT...............................................

Hi! So now I have made a new dart file where I inserted the code below which I got help about. But What I now do not understand is to activate the code is that it will be run in my flutter application. Because in the debugger the results shows that combine is 0 in index even when I run the app. So I guess I have not called on the file in the correct way?

```
import 'package:shop_app/models/Image.dart';
import 'package:shop_app/models/ProductInfo.dart';



void main() {


var pictureList  = new List<Images>();
var userList  = new List<ProductInfo>();


List<Combine> combineList = new List<Combine>();
userList.forEach((user) {
  Images picture = pictureList.firstWhere((pic) => pic.productId == user.productId);
  if (picture != null) {
    combineList.add(Combine(user, picture));
  }
});

combineList.forEach((combine) {
  print("User id: ${combine.user.productId}  User name: 
${combine.user.productNameBold}");
  print(
      "Picture id: ${combine.product.productId}  Picture url: 
 ${combine.product.plink}");
  print("---------------------------------- \n");
   });
 }



 class Combine {
 ProductInfo user;
 Images product;
 Combine(this.user, this.product);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create a new class that holds your User and Product. Then you should run a loop and match the id of both User and Product. Here is an example

```
void main() {
  List<User> userList = [
    User(1, "one"),
    User(2, "two"),
    User(3, "three"),
  ];
  List<Product> pictureList = [
    Product(1, "oneImg"),
    Product(2, "twoImg"),
    Product(3, "threeImg"),
  ];
  List<Combine> combineList = new List<Combine>();
  userList.forEach((user) {
    Product picture = pictureList.firstWhere((pic) => pic.id == user.id);
    if (picture != null) {
      combineList.add(Combine(user, picture));
    }
  });

  combineList.forEach((combine) {
    print("User id: ${combine.user.id}  User name: ${combine.user.name}");
    print(
        "Picture id: ${combine.product.id}  Picture url: ${combine.product.image}");
    print("---------------------------------- \n");
  });
}

class User {
  int id;
  String name;
  User(this.id, this.name);
}

class Product {
  int id;
  String image;
  Product(this.id, this.image);
}

class Combine {
  User user;
  Product product;
  Combine(this.user, this.product);
}
```

**Output:**

```
User id: 1  User name: one
Product id: 1  Product image: oneImg
---------------------------------- 

User id: 2  User name: two
Product id: 2  Product image: twoImg
---------------------------------- 

User id: 3  User name: three
Product id: 3  Product image: threeImg
----------------------------------
```

In your case after combine User and Product in a list then use that list in your widget.

**Full Code:**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'APIE.dart';
import 'Image.dart';
import 'ProductInfo.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var pictureList = new List<Images>();
  var userList = new List<ProductInfo>();
  bool dataGet = false;



  _getImage() {
    API.getImage().then((response) {
        Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
        pictureList = list.map((model) => Images.fromJson(model)).toList();
        _conmineList();
    });
  }

  _getUsers() {
    API.getUsers().then((response) {
        Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
        userList = list.map((model) => ProductInfo.fromJson(model)).toList();
        _getImage();
    });
  }

  _conmineList(){
    userList.forEach((user) {
      Images picture = pictureList.firstWhere((pic) => pic.productId == user.productId);
      if (picture != null) {
        combineList.add(Combine(user, picture));
      }
    });
    setState(() {
      dataGet = true;
    });
  }




  List<Combine> combineList = new List<Combine>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getUsers();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: dataGet?ListView.builder(
            itemCount: userList.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
              title: Text("${userList[index].productId}"),
              subtitle: Text("${pictureList[index].productId}" + "${combineList[index].product.productId}" ),

            ),
          ):Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        ));
  }
}


class Combine {
  ProductInfo user;
  Images product;
  Combine(this.user, this.product);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
I am trying this solution out but with my list. However I am really new and have hard to time understand how I will call this on my app. I have made a new file and copied your code. Then I replaced your code with my two datasets. Then when I run the app in the debugger it shows only the value 0 as index and it seems to me that the for loop has not been executed. I do not know or understand how to call my new file with your code.

Comment: @Yax, Above code is a demo code. It's written on dart only. In your project from where you get the two types of list (User and Product) you should apply this code there. After getting those list (User and Product) you should run userList.forEach((user) {.... this piece of code to combine them. And don't forget to make the Combine class.

Comment: or you can provide the code, from where you get those lists.

Comment: Hi! I have added the code I have used from you and how I get the other data you asked about  @TipuSultan

Comment: Thank you! Please check my latest edit, I manage to do all but somehow not get a single value for the new variable combinelist

Comment: you get null value because you call userList.forEach((user) {... before your Images and ProductInfo list being called.

Comment: I have made some change in your code, please check the answer

Comment: Worked good! Thank you. Please check my next question regarding best practice about backend in flutter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63575093/how-much-backend-logic-should-be-done-in-flutter-compared-to-the-sql-database-i